# is there download manager like IDM for automatically fetching link address of streaming video?

Tags: 12.04, download-manager

is there any download manager that can be freely integrated to chromium or firefox, so that it will fetch the remote link url of any audio, video during streaming.

I have used steadyflow download manager and recently installed Flareget, but still getting trouble for downloading streaming videos.

Is there any better way..?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

if you use Firefox or seabird i think you should use Add on of Firefox
for example Downthemall replace idm and video download helper to catch video link

Comment: yeah i tried it. But still, its not capturing the link automatically. And, whenever I try to copy video link from any site, for e.g. youtube; it downloads the HTML page...

Comment: I want something to capture video link automatically like IDM does...

Comment: @user92674 Use FlareGet + flashgot for firefox. The two work seamlessly with each other provided you install flareget from its website. As far as chrome is concerned, google has banned all the extensions with which you could download youtube videos. In that case FlareGet is the only choice. Today FlareGet 1.4-9 was released which supports chrome too. You can download youtube videos using free version too. Just start the grabber and play videos in youtube. Change video quality in flash player to download videos of different quality.

Comment: @adnankamili thanks for help, I tried it for firefox. But, its not getting the download link from streaming video on youtube. However, it provides an elegant way of downloading all media content on that webpage. Ya, its a good tool, but still didn't get what I needed.

Comment: @user92674 I am surprised, did you try the grabber or flashgot. Flashgot never fails, are you sure how flashgot works!